# Can not off output by xrandr

Tags: kde, xrandr

I have 2 monitors, one connect by VGA, one connect by HDMI. When I unplug VGA, the status is still "connected". Xrandr cannot off output VGA. Do you resolve this problem?

Comment: When the VGA monitor is connected, do you have problem to switch it off with `xrandr --output <your VGA output> --off` ?

Comment: When VGA is connected, I off by xrandr, the monitor is off but VGA status printed by xrandr still "connected".